# Case Time Tracking in Service Cloud - Is it possible?

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, salesforce1-platform

We are considering using Service Cloud in my company and I was not able to find straight forward answer on one question.

Does SF Service Cloud has an option which would allow my agents to record time they spend working on a case? In addition to this, I would need to be able to report on that monthly, quarterly, yearly etc.

So far I found information about apps on AppExchange we could use, but I was wondering if SF offers this out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this feature i.e., the ability to track time on cases is available OOB however, there is an open idea that you can check and upvote so that if it reaches necessary votes it may be considered in the future.

[Link to idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006uB4AAI)

Answer (score 0):

found a really simple, free app from Salesforce Labs to do this- so cool! Wanted to post here in case anyone else was searching for this: [Case Timer for Service Console](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000QsyVxEAJ).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to find a solution to time tracking but you might want to check out my company's Time Tracking solution built native on the Salesforce platform. We built it for our own user when tracking billable time so it is something I use daily and we are constantly improving upon it.

- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FnF37UAF&tab=e

If you are interested in a demo and talking more set up a meeting with us

- https://calendly.com/mattfoster/app-demo

Answer (score -1):

You can integrate Salesforce with a time tracking app. I work at TimeCamp so
in my company we use that app and personally it turns out very well to keep everything in order. This page gives you a better look of how it works: https://www.timecamp.com/integrations/salesforce-time-tracking/

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! If you are affiliated with TimeCamp in any way, that is not in itself an issue, but please do not misrepresent that you are a customer. From a section of the SFSE Help Center (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): *"Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers**."* (emphasis added)